# How to login to my site again after all users were deleted?

Tags: users

I was inside `/admin` on my site looking at users. I noticed a lot of what looked like robot made users and I decided to delete them. I clicked the box for delete all on this page. What happened then is that all users were deleted and now I cannot login at all.

All clients linked with whitelabel show error message.

What can I do?

Comment: Contact the hosting company and ask for restoration from backup.

Comment: I did they say thaey can do a server rewind. But they are not sure if the access will be restored. And I am afraid that even more might be destroyed.. Cannot understand the logics in the site disappearing from all whitelabel accounts   just because the login inof is gone.

Comment: If you roll back the database to before you made the change it should be ok (take a backup of the current database first). However you will also lose any other data changes that happened between the time of the backup and now. If there aren't many maybe you can make those changes manually again after the restore.

Comment: Well there cannot have been any changes to it after the disaster as no one can access it...

Comment: @patrick, rooby means that if your most recent backup is from 2 days ago, then you will lose any changes that have been made to your database after that backup was taken. That's why he recommends taking a backup of your current mashed up database just in case you need to manually copy some data from it.

Comment: You need to restore users from backup. There is no other way, simple as that. If you didn't use any in-Drupal backup means, you need to use what you can. If it means loosing data, then take a database backup now, rewind server, and restore data (except user-related data that was "updated" in a way you don't want).

Comment: I have done the restore but the problem remains.. cannot login. according to a guy who could look inside the DB he says there are no users at all and this is why all links are broken ..

Comment: Well sounds like you didn't restore from an *earlier* backup, but restored from the backup you've made on the day? The former is what people are suggesting, not the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have backups then restore from backup then delete users again without deleting the ones you want to keep.

If you don't have a backup then you will need at least user 0 (anonymous) and user 1 (superuser).

I am assuming Drupal 7 because you didn't specify version.

You will have to add those back into the database either via database access in your hosting administration area or from the command line.

Note: I am adding the basic MySQL queries here but you should read these whole linked pages for more information.

The process is similar for both users.
You should read [Restore user 0](https://www.drupal.org/node/1029506) for more detailed information but here are the SQL queries:

**User 0 (anonymous):**

```
INSERT INTO users (name, pass, mail, theme, signature, language, init, timezone) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
UPDATE users SET uid = 1 WHERE name = '';
```

**User 1 (superuser):** You can change "admin to whatever user name you want to use. I recommend not using "admin" because attackers will try that first if trying to work out your password.

```
INSERT INTO users (name, pass, mail, theme, signature, language, init, timezone) VALUES ('admin', '', 'youremail@example.com', '', '', '', 'youremail@example.com', '');
UPDATE users SET uid = 0 WHERE name = 'admin';
```

Then you will need to do a password reset for the user 1 account.

**Other users**
Other users can be added just with the first insert statement without the update statement after however you will lose settings like user picture, signature etc. if there is data in those fields (or unless you know what the data should be and ad it back in).

Those users would also not get roles so you would have to assign roles to them after.

They also wouldn't have the same UID as before so in the uncommon case that you have code that specifically references a user ID that will need consideration.

**Note** that some modules that change the behavior of Drupal users may change the way you need to add these users back.

For example if you user the "User revisions" module then there is also a user_revision database table that needs to be considered when doing these queries.